# Accesing a method in the last object in a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, bluej, linkedhashmap

I've got a LinkedHashMap that contains an object at `key` and one at `value`.

I've used the code

```
yourShots.keySet().toArray()[yourShots.size()-1]
```

to return the last object of the `keys`. However, I am unable to access a method that the object has.

I've used the `getClass()` method to determine that I do indeed have the right kind of object, but the method cannot be called. I simply get the error that the method cannot be found.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that the method you're trying to call is on the *value* object, not the *key* object, of the key/value pairs that is in the `Map`?

Comment: Can you show to what variable you assign the result to and the declaration of yourShots.

Comment: If you know the *key*, there is no need to construct an array

Comment: Show more code. How is yourShots defined? Maybe you need a cast...

Comment: @Andreas No. The method lies in the `key` object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`toArray` give you generic `Object` type. You have to cast it to your `key` class before using it.

```
KeyClass key = (KeyClass) yourShots.keySet().toArray()[yourShots.size()-1];
// Here you can access your desired method
```

**Edit:**

As @rgettman suggest, you could use the overloaded version `toArray(T[])` to avoid the cast. In this case you should provide an initialized array with size of `keySet()` beforehand.

Comment: Or you can use the overload [`Set.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray-T:A-) to avoid the cast.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use an `Iterator` to avoid copying all the unwanted keys to an array just to throw it away afterwards. It also saves the cast due to being generic.

```
Key key = null;
for(Iterator<Key> iterator = yourShots.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    key = iterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
You can convert your `keySet` into a `List` and then get the last object.
Something like this:

```
List<Key> keys = new ArrayList(yourShots.keySet());
Key lastKey = keys.get(keys.size() - 1);
```

**Original Post**
You're accessing the wrong method.

`yourShots.keySet()` returns a `Set` containing all keys in your `Map`.

in order to access the last value in your map, you need to call: `yourShots.values()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to get the last value. I'm trying to get the last key.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question, let me update my answer.